# Posix variable for JAI Image I/O

Tags: linux, posix, geoserver

I was trying to install JAI Image I/O for geoserver, reading the official documentation of geoserver, indicates that for installation of JAI I have to chande Posix environment variable like this,

```
export _POSIX2_VERSION=199209
```

I've done that and I want to role back that change, but don't know waht version a had. I'm running a Linux Server 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, _POSIX2_VERSION is not set.
Just unset it:

```
$ unset _POSIX2_VERSION
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer FredEtHop, and how can I see the status of that variable?